# setting attribute in __init__ with method in python?

Tags: python, class, attributes

I'm learning python. I'd like for `self.characteristic` to be set to 5 when an object of the class is created. I'm using the `set.characteristic` method, because in reality there would be a bunch of calculations to reach the value 5. I'd expect the output of my code below to be 5, but I get None. Why? Thanks!

```
class AnyClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.characteristic = self.set_characteristic()


    def set_characteristic(self):
        # in reality would do a bunch of calculations 
        self.characteristic = 5


obj = AnyClass()
print(obj.characteristic)

# Output: None 
# Expected output: 5
```

Comment: Because `self.characteristic = self.set_characteristic()`, and `self.set_characteristic()` (having no explicit `return`) implicitly returns `None`. `self.characteristic = 5` only until the invocation completes and the caller overwrites it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to `return` the desired value in your function.

```
def set_characteristic(self):
    # in reality would do a bunch of calculations 
    return 5
```

When you do not return a value, function returns `None`.

Comment: That's not actually Python, please do test before posting.

Answer (score 0):

Controversial maybe but my preference is for "lazy" assignment of attributes when the values are not constant (e.g., need to be calculated)

The reasoning is that you might construct a class but not necessarily access all attributes (properties). Therefore, providing the actual value will never be None, you can do something like this:

```
class AnyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._characteristic = None
    @property
    def characteristic(self):
        if self._characteristic is None:
            self._characteristic = self.calculate_characteristic()
        return self._characteristic 
    def calculate_characteristic(self):
        # do complex stuff here
        return 5

c = AnyClass()

print(c.characteristic)
```

If the value could be None then you need a complementary flag to indicate whether our not the value has vbeen calculated.

Like this:

```
class AnyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._characteristic = None
        self._calculated = False
    @property
    def characteristic(self):
        if not self._calculated:
            self._characteristic = self.calculate_characteristic()
            self._calculated = True
        return self._characteristic 
    def calculate_characteristic(self):
        # do complex stuff here
        return 5
```

Comment: From Python 3.8+ you can use [`cached_property`](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/functools.html#functools.cached_property) to avoid most of the boilerplate.

Comment: @AKX I did not know about the functools.cached_property decorator. You learn something new every day. Thank you